# Getting an error when parsing a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, maven

I'm trying to get a data from an online JSON, so getting the json and printing it works without issue, but when I want a particular data, my IDE give me this error

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I tried many solutions but none works for me, or I'm still too novice to adapt solution to my code, it will be very nice if someone can help me with this! I'm stuck on it since a long moment now.

So here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("src/main/java/ressources/config.txt");
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String url = "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k=" + list.get(1) + "&u=" + list.get(0);

        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(readUrl(url));

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl(url));

            String mydata = (String) json.get("ranked_score");
            System.out.println(mydata);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSON give me this

```
[{"user_id":"11726408","username":"Synaelle","join_date":"2018-02-11 16:29:55","count300":"6704495","count100":"1000221","count50":"108185","playcount":"43799","ranked_score":"19227444109","total_score":"46034426831","pp_rank":"48400","level":"100.191","pp_raw":"4936.2","accuracy":"98.12742614746094","count_rank_ss":"144","count_rank_ssh":"502","count_rank_s":"1002","count_rank_sh":"817","count_rank_a":"1249","country":"FR","total_seconds_played":"2291574","pp_country_rank":"1867","events":[{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/X_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #9<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2701763?m=0'>Katy Perry - E.T. (Cut Ver.) [Collab Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2701763","beatmapset_id":"1060234","date":"2021-01-12 23:57:24","epicfactor":"4"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #14<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2768636?m=0'>Katy Perry - E.T. (Cut Ver.) [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2768636","beatmapset_id":"1060234","date":"2021-01-12 23:55:58","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #13<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1918437?m=0'>Justice - D.A.N.C.E. [Gens' Choreo]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1918437","beatmapset_id":"875221","date":"2021-01-12 23:54:24","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #12<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2755561?m=0'>Justice - D.A.N.C.E. [Warm Up]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2755561","beatmapset_id":"875221","date":"2021-01-12 23:51:40","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #843 on <a href='\/b\/2202872?m=0'>ViViD - HIKARI (TV Size) [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2202872","beatmapset_id":"1053509","date":"2021-01-12 23:48:29","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #623 on <a href='\/b\/203363?m=0'>Kirsten Price - We Will Be Heroes (TV Size) [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"203363","beatmapset_id":"70073","date":"2021-01-12 23:44:29","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #326 on <a href='\/b\/355974?m=0'>DJ YOSHITAKA - CUSTOM DRIVE [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"355974","beatmapset_id":"142937","date":"2021-01-12 23:43:53","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #229 on <a href='\/b\/2282184?m=0'>Iiyoshi Arata, Ishizuna Atsuhiro - Pokemon Kyuu Jotai no Thema [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2282184","beatmapset_id":"1091644","date":"2021-01-12 23:43:19","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #690 on <a href='\/b\/2245770?m=0'>Turbo - PADORU \/ PADORU [Collab Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2245770","beatmapset_id":"1073074","date":"2021-01-12 23:42:48","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #696 on <a href='\/b\/515123?m=0'>Yamanote Line - Yamanoted heaven [Yamanote Line x Second_heaven] [Maeglwn's Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"515123","beatmapset_id":"176702","date":"2021-01-12 23:41:13","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #957 on <a href='\/b\/313405?m=0'>Selena Gomez - Everything Is Not What It Seems (Season 4 Remix) [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"313405","beatmapset_id":"122568","date":"2021-01-12 23:38:34","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #336 on <a href='\/b\/2328397?m=0'>saradisk - 222 - wewewe [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2328397","beatmapset_id":"1114649","date":"2021-01-12 23:37:38","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #213 on <a href='\/b\/2316798?m=0'>Earth Star Dream - Hashire! Usakame Koukou Tennis-bu!! (TV Size) [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2316798","beatmapset_id":"1108575","date":"2021-01-12 23:36:54","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #805 on <a href='\/b\/1372429?m=0'>Takamori Natsumi, Sendai Eri, Asakawa Yuu, Tanezaki Atsumi - Ne! Ko! [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1372429","beatmapset_id":"647383","date":"2021-01-12 23:34:47","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #393 on <a href='\/b\/1348161?m=0'>55x55 - TIPA PRIVIDENIE (feat. Utopia Show) [HARD NAMKI SHOW]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1348161","beatmapset_id":"634648","date":"2021-01-12 23:34:03","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #229 on <a href='\/b\/775575?m=0'>Go Ichinose - Shitennou Toujou! [Zetera's Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"775575","beatmapset_id":"338333","date":"2021-01-12 23:32:02","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #657 on <a href='\/b\/418041?m=0'>Chili Tomato - Angel Gakuen no Ichinichi [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"418041","beatmapset_id":"172967","date":"2021-01-12 23:30:09","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #400 on <a href='\/b\/2342693?m=0'>BLANKFIELD - Falling Falls [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2342693","beatmapset_id":"1120635","date":"2021-01-12 23:28:17","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #534 on <a href='\/b\/716270?m=0'>Renard - Layers Of Shit [Sharkie's Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"716270","beatmapset_id":"322121","date":"2021-01-12 23:24:42","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #342 on <a href='\/b\/1255850?m=0'>David Wise - Title Theme [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1255850","beatmapset_id":"593496","date":"2021-01-12 23:22:35","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #18<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/615539?m=0'>SCREEN mode - LOVEST(TV Size Ver.) [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"615539","beatmapset_id":"265859","date":"2021-01-12 23:20:03","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #27<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/751649?m=0'>Neru x Rib - Jinsei wa Hoeru [apple's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"751649","beatmapset_id":"245393","date":"2021-01-12 23:17:28","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #72 on <a href='\/b\/1454910?m=0'>Himeringo - Shinitai-chan [Noffy's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1454910","beatmapset_id":"519318","date":"2021-01-12 23:15:06","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #28<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1131031?m=0'>All Time Low - Merry Christmas, Kiss My Ass [Mkael's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1131031","beatmapset_id":"533683","date":"2021-01-12 23:12:43","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #8<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1860766?m=0'>P.D.P. - A Word To The Wise [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1860766","beatmapset_id":"890157","date":"2021-01-12 23:09:49","epicfactor":"4"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #30<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2123919?m=0'>Vickeblanka - Black Rover [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2123919","beatmapset_id":"913669","date":"2021-01-12 23:03:51","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #41<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/615621?m=0'>senya - Kimi to Dareka no Yasashisa ni [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"615621","beatmapset_id":"250337","date":"2021-01-12 23:01:19","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #42<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1684158?m=0'>Nanahira - Viva Happy [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1684158","beatmapset_id":"672621","date":"2021-01-12 22:58:14","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #34<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2232545?m=0'>TORIENA - RAT RACE [Collab Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2232545","beatmapset_id":"1027510","date":"2021-01-12 22:54:03","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #193 on <a href='\/b\/1024814?m=0'>Kano - Yuudachi no Ribbon [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1024814","beatmapset_id":"456237","date":"2021-01-12 22:51:18","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #49<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1066879?m=0'>Ayane - FaV -F*** and Vanguard- [Satellite's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1066879","beatmapset_id":"494460","date":"2021-01-12 22:48:27","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #19<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1271445?m=0'>BTS - Not Today [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1271445","beatmapset_id":"575767","date":"2021-01-12 22:44:19","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #30<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/957614?m=0'>charon - Seventeen RPG [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"957614","beatmapset_id":"304888","date":"2021-01-12 22:41:28","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #22<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1052902?m=0'>nano x buzzG - Dive In Your Eyes [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1052902","beatmapset_id":"302884","date":"2021-01-12 22:30:45","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #149 on <a href='\/b\/824386?m=0'>Hana - Sakura no Uta [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"824386","beatmapset_id":"376552","date":"2021-01-12 22:27:44","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #22<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1359014?m=0'>Akitsuki Fuuka CV:Lynn - Fair wind [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1359014","beatmapset_id":"587541","date":"2021-01-12 22:09:34","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #41<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1512594?m=0'>GEM - Umiyuri Kaiteitan [Icekalt's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1512594","beatmapset_id":"647452","date":"2021-01-12 22:06:12","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #11<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1388283?m=0'>Iris Freyja(CV:Rina Hidaka), Mitsuki Mononobe(CV:Manami Numakura) - Ray of bullet [Collab Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1388283","beatmapset_id":"628968","date":"2021-01-12 22:02:56","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #15<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1553941?m=0'>YUC'e - Future Cider [Ayyri's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1553941","beatmapset_id":"720558","date":"2021-01-12 21:59:52","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #44<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1418648?m=0'>BTS - DNA [Lilyanna's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1418648","beatmapset_id":"670560","date":"2021-01-12 21:56:59","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #9<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1486685?m=0'>Usa - Akane Contrast [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1486685","beatmapset_id":"699833","date":"2021-01-12 21:53:50","epicfactor":"4"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #24<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/937186?m=0'>Petit Rabbit's - No Poi! (nenpulse bootleg remix) [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"937186","beatmapset_id":"414348","date":"2021-01-12 21:50:28","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #11<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/657476?m=0'>Demetori - Shoujo Satori ~ Innumerable Eyes [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"657476","beatmapset_id":"288656","date":"2021-01-12 21:45:36","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #19<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/468841?m=0'>xi - Akasha [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"468841","beatmapset_id":"118768","date":"2021-01-12 21:39:59","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #21<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1865252?m=0'>Kimunyu - Snow halation (REDSHiFT Remix) [NicoRin Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1865252","beatmapset_id":"429540","date":"2021-01-12 21:36:50","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #24<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/816397?m=0'>Eiko Shimamiya - Higurashi no Naku Koro ni [Noz's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"816397","beatmapset_id":"333543","date":"2021-01-12 21:33:17","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #17<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/992390?m=0'>Kitamura Eri - alive [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"992390","beatmapset_id":"462730","date":"2021-01-12 21:26:22","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #15<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1117675?m=0'>SCANDAL - Image [Yuii-'s Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1117675","beatmapset_id":"466737","date":"2021-01-12 21:22:37","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #95 on <a href='\/b\/1625590?m=0'>Nanamori-chu * Goraku-bu - Happy Time wa Owaranai [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1625590","beatmapset_id":"773330","date":"2021-01-12 21:16:21","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #48<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1509645?m=0'>96neko - Uso no Hibana [Lafa's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1509645","beatmapset_id":"625669","date":"2021-01-12 21:04:54","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #64 on <a href='\/b\/1885268?m=0'>FLOW - Kaze no Uta (TV Size) [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1885268","beatmapset_id":"901211","date":"2021-01-12 21:03:17","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #68 on <a href='\/b\/1300077?m=0'>Kensho Ono - STORY (TV Size) [Hobbes2's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1300077","beatmapset_id":"598357","date":"2021-01-12 21:01:48","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #60 on <a href='\/b\/1074012?m=0'>Stonebank - Who's Got Your Love [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1074012","beatmapset_id":"496549","date":"2021-01-12 21:00:10","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/XH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #55 on <a href='\/b\/1108752?m=0'>BLACKPINK - BOOMBAYAH [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1108752","beatmapset_id":"500858","date":"2021-01-12 20:58:54","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #38<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1964744?m=0'>Erabareshi - Picon de Metafiction [Crissa's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1964744","beatmapset_id":"913092","date":"2021-01-12 20:55:34","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #41<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/1731443?m=0'>Dethklok - Fansong (Cut Ver.) [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1731443","beatmapset_id":"810450","date":"2021-01-12 20:53:48","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #76 on <a href='\/b\/1930469?m=0'>soraru - Gin no Kisei (TV Size) [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1930469","beatmapset_id":"920713","date":"2021-01-12 20:52:18","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #36<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2447566?m=0'>Numtack05 - Ooki na Hane de! (Cut Ver.) [L3NNy's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2447566","beatmapset_id":"1075635","date":"2021-01-12 20:51:10","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #64 on <a href='\/b\/2350601?m=0'>Three feat. Kagamine Len - Ego Rock [nyu's Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2350601","beatmapset_id":"1122938","date":"2021-01-12 20:49:47","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #15<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2463212?m=0'>Kano - Kimi ga Iru Sekai e [Advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2463212","beatmapset_id":"1175013","date":"2021-01-12 20:34:59","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #572 on <a href='\/b\/1724593?m=0'>mito - white lies (TV Size) [advanced]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"1724593","beatmapset_id":"817394","date":"2021-01-12 20:29:58","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/S_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #30<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2722836?m=0'>Yamamoto Mineko - Shiroi Sakura Saite [Ex &amp; Kowari's Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2722836","beatmapset_id":"1313749","date":"2021-01-12 20:25:53","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #26<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2722838?m=0'>Yamamoto Mineko - Shiroi Sakura Saite [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2722838","beatmapset_id":"1313749","date":"2021-01-12 20:20:35","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #30<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2722835?m=0'>Yamamoto Mineko - Shiroi Sakura Saite [Easy]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2722835","beatmapset_id":"1313749","date":"2021-01-12 20:17:33","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #286 on <a href='\/b\/2700999?m=0'>The Winking Owl - Let Go [Farewell]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2700999","beatmapset_id":"1302335","date":"2021-01-12 20:13:43","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #80 on <a href='\/b\/2729826?m=0'>The Winking Owl - Let Go [Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2729826","beatmapset_id":"1302335","date":"2021-01-12 20:09:40","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #76 on <a href='\/b\/2737143?m=0'>The Winking Owl - Let Go [Hard]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2737143","beatmapset_id":"1302335","date":"2021-01-12 20:05:18","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #31<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2724200?m=0'>The Winking Owl - Let Go [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2724200","beatmapset_id":"1302335","date":"2021-01-12 20:01:57","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/SH_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #17<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2757241?m=0'>senya - Koborezu no Negaigoto [Normal]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2757241","beatmapset_id":"1330002","date":"2021-01-12 19:14:28","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #70 on <a href='\/b\/2748129?m=0'>Kano - glow [Hikare]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2748129","beatmapset_id":"1326497","date":"2021-01-12 19:06:07","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/C_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #410 on <a href='\/b\/2689510?m=0'>Yousei Teikoku - Paradiso=Inferno [Doku Ringo]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2689510","beatmapset_id":"1296273","date":"2021-01-12 19:00:33","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/C_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #180 on <a href='\/b\/2750915?m=0'>Yousei Teikoku - Paradiso=Inferno [Net0's Extra]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2750915","beatmapset_id":"1296273","date":"2021-01-12 18:55:53","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #163 on <a href='\/b\/2708899?m=0'>Yousei Teikoku - Paradiso=Inferno [Expert]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2708899","beatmapset_id":"1296273","date":"2021-01-12 18:50:24","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #84 on <a href='\/b\/2750914?m=0'>Yousei Teikoku - Paradiso=Inferno [Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2750914","beatmapset_id":"1296273","date":"2021-01-12 18:46:30","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #32<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2763986?m=0'>Yousei Teikoku - Paradiso=Inferno [Dada's Light Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2763986","beatmapset_id":"1296273","date":"2021-01-12 18:42:38","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #252 on <a href='\/b\/2769648?m=0'>Linkin Park vs. Sally - Min the end [Faito's One Expert Thing]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769648","beatmapset_id":"1336972","date":"2021-01-12 18:38:11","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #58 on <a href='\/b\/2769651?m=0'>Linkin Park vs. Sally - Min the end [Melwoine's One Expert Thing]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769651","beatmapset_id":"1336972","date":"2021-01-12 18:36:24","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #39<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2769649?m=0'>Linkin Park vs. Sally - Min the end [hypercyte's One Insane Thing]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769649","beatmapset_id":"1336972","date":"2021-01-12 18:32:56","epicfactor":"2"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #83 on <a href='\/b\/2769652?m=0'>Linkin Park vs. Sally - Min the end [One Light Insane Thing]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769652","beatmapset_id":"1336972","date":"2021-01-12 18:30:10","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #88 on <a href='\/b\/2769653?m=0'>Linkin Park vs. Sally - Min the end [Suouyume's One Hard Thing]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769653","beatmapset_id":"1336972","date":"2021-01-12 18:28:45","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #309 on <a href='\/b\/2596847?m=0'>TUYU - Rock na Kimi to wa Owakare da [Nathan's Extra]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2596847","beatmapset_id":"1158494","date":"2021-01-12 18:18:41","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #114 on <a href='\/b\/2417645?m=0'>TUYU - Rock na Kimi to wa Owakare da [Farewell Extra]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2417645","beatmapset_id":"1158494","date":"2021-01-12 18:15:03","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #51 on <a href='\/b\/2711135?m=0'>TUYU - Rock na Kimi to wa Owakare da [too's Insane]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2711135","beatmapset_id":"1158494","date":"2021-01-12 18:11:19","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/B_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved rank #110 on <a href='\/b\/2769279?m=0'>YUI - LIFE (TV Size) [Six Princess Shielding Flowers]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2769279","beatmapset_id":"1175059","date":"2021-01-12 18:06:48","epicfactor":"1"},{"display_html":"<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/> <b><a href='\/u\/11726408'>Synaelle<\/a><\/b> achieved <b>rank #44<\/b> on <a href='\/b\/2450952?m=0'>YUI - LIFE (TV Size) [Extra]<\/a> (osu!)","beatmap_id":"2450952","beatmapset_id":"1175059","date":"2021-01-12 18:05:04","epicfactor":"1"}]}]
```

Comment: I may be wrong but to me it looks like the JSON you got doesn't start with `{`.  So it gives an error when it tries parsing the JSON.

Comment: Yeah that's what I try to fix, I see a lot of fixes about converting this to an jsonarray but can't get this to work

Comment: Try removing the first and last characters (`[` and `]`) from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an array at the top level instead of a JSON object. You should use JSONArray instead of JSONObject to parse the inital response object.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl(url));
```

to

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(readUrl(url));
```

Then you need to grab an object out of the array

```
JSONObject object = json.getJSONObject(0);
object.getString("ranked_score");
```

The fact that you are getting an Array response likely means there is or can be more than one object in the response.  You may only have to deal with the first object in the array but it depends on what exactly the endpoint is returning.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, it works perfectly! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your previous line:

```java
String content=readUrl(url);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content.substring(1,content.length()-1);
```

This will remove the `[` and `]` from outside so it will become a valid JSON object without breaking anything.

Comment: @Arishia : I would prefer Deadron's method because strings are immutable and it looks like your JSON data is large so this may not be as memory friendly as the other solution.